# Can I use get_adjacent_post for specific categories?

Tags: categories, taxonomy, next-post-link, previous-post-link

I want to get next and previous posts based on a particular category slugs. For example, some posts might have the "sports" category while another has the "tech" category.

I was hoping to plug in a category slug into `get_adjacent_post` but it doesn't appear that it's working. It looks like it just wants use the slug "category" or maybe custom taxonomies rather than slugs within the "category" taxonomy.

Here's an example of what I was trying to do:

```
$adj = get_adjacent_post(true, '', true, 'sports');
```

Answer (score 2):

What you call "slugs" here is more appropriately called *terms*. It is a little confusing with native taxonomies because it turns into tautology: individual categories are *terms* of the category *taxonomy*.

So `sports` and `tech` are terms of native `category` taxonomy.

The function arguments operate on *taxonomy* level, not *term* level. That is you need to provide a taxonomy slug, such as `category`, and *all* of the terms in that taxonomy will be considered for a match.

From arguments point of view one of the options here is to use `$excluded_terms` argument to exclude everything but the one term you want.

Other than that it's pretty low level function, which directly generates a lot of custom SQL. There are abundant filters for manipulating that part of the process, like `get_{$adjacent}_post_join` and `get_{$adjacent}_post_where`, but it's not something I would call *easily* adjustable.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation for `get_adjacent_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_adjacent_post/), the parameters are:

> `$in_same_term` (bool) (Optional) Whether post should be in a same
>   taxonomy term.
>   Default value: `false`
>
> `$excluded_terms` (array|string) (Optional) Array or comma-separated
>   list of excluded term IDs.
>   Default value: `''`
>
> `$previous` (bool) (Optional) Whether to retrieve previous post.
>   Default value: `true`
>
> `$taxonomy` (string) (Optional) Taxonomy, if `$in_same_term`
>   is `true`.
>   Default value: `'category'`

The `$taxonomy` parameter is so you can specify which taxonomy (category, tag, or custom taxonomy) you'd like use to select the adjacent post.

So no, it appears you can't specify the taxonomy term (eg, `sports` or `tech` in your question).